# What is the correct id for terraform import of resource type api_gateway_base_path_mapping

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to import an existing custom domain mapping in AWS api gateway into my terraform state.

I've followed the format specified [in the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_base_path_mapping#import), which is:

```
terraform import aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping.example example.com/base-path
```

I tried with and without including the subdomain part. However this does not successfully locate the existing infrastructure and nothing is imported.

The output says "import successful, the above list resources were imported", but no resources are listed, and plan still shows it wants to create the resource as a new resource.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Marcin no. It said "import successful", above resources were imported, but no resources are listed, and plan still shows it wants to create it.